# Erase Duplicated Edges that are being read from a file

Tags: c, file-io, duplicates

I wrote a code that reads edges from different files (node1 and node2 ... which are the origin node and destination node).

However, these files might have duplicated edges (same node1 and node2 being read).
How to erase these duplicated edges?? Can anyone provide with a C code for this?
 A sample c code at least?

P.S: I want to keep record of the actual number of edges (meaning without the duplicated ones).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `edges`?

Comment: Can you give an example of the format of an `edge`? How do you read it? How close do two values have to be to be considered "duplicate"? Recognize that in floating point, "equal" is a fuzzy concept… but if these are "edge" in a graph sense (nodes are integers) it might be done.

Comment: For example, an edge from a file could be 3 4
which means that there is a flow from node 3 to node 4 .. I want to make sure that this flow from 3 to 4 only happens once! hence I want to duplicate the others! how to translate that into code?

Comment: When you say "erase duplicated edges" do you mean you want to ignore duplicate edges while building the container your reading them in to, or you want to erase them from the input file from which they're read? The former is trivial, the latter slightly less-so.

Comment: erase duplicated edges means that when I find that the same edge is read twice or more, I only write it once and I only count it once in the final n umber of edges

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have edges as the connection between two nodes N1 and N2, and that these are directional (so N1 -> N2 is different from N2 -> N1), then the problem becomes one of sorting the edges, and taking the unique values. Depending on the platform you are using, you may have utilities built in to do this. For example, if you run on Linux/Mac platform, you might do the following:

1. Read in all the edges, and don't care about duplicates (yet)
2. Print the edges (N1 space N2) as a long list to text file (including duplicates)
3. Sort the file
4. Send the result of the sort to the `uniq` command; the result will be a (sorted) list of unique edges.
5. Count the number of lines from the output of `uniq` - that's the number of distinct edges.

Example:

```
>cat inputFile.txt
2 3
3 4
4 5
3 4
4 3
1 2
2 3

>sort inputFile.txt | uniq
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 3
4 5

>>sort inputFile.txt | uniq -c
   1     1 2
   2     2 3
   2     3 4
   1     4 3
   1     4 5
```

This shows the number of times each edge was seen

```
>>sort inputFile.txt | uniq | wc -l
5
```

This shows how many edges there were in total.

You can write your own C code to do this if you don't have utilities like this on your platform; but it's more work than using what already exists.

**UPDATE** here is some *inefficient* code that does what you are asking for. Inefficient, because the `isnew` function checks all previous elements (order N^2 operation). This is OK for small sets, and becomes really bad for large ones - but you get the idea. If you sort the array you can make this more efficient, but I can't write that code for you. There are many things you can do to improve this code - error checking etc. This is just a "push in the general direction", you should be able to take it from here (or hire someone to write your code for you…)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NE 20

int isnew(int* e, int nd[NE][2], int n) {
// return 0 if same edge is found in nd
  int ii;
  for(ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
    if(e[0] == nd[ii][0] && e[1] == nd[ii][1]) return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp;
  char buf[NE]; // to read in lines
  int ii, uc, rowCount;
  int edges[NE][2]; // make it big enough
  int nodup[NE][2]; // only unique edges
  fp = fopen("inputFile.txt", "r");
  if(fp == NULL) {
    printf("file not found\n");
    return -1;
  }

  ii = 0;
  while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) && ii < NE) {
    if(sscanf(buf, "%d %d", &edges[ii][0], &edges[ii][1]) != 2) break;
    ii++;

  }
  fclose(fp);
  rowCount = ii;
  printf("all elements read in: \n");
  for(ii = 0; ii < rowCount; ii++) {
    printf("%d %d\n", edges[ii][0], edges[ii][1]);
  }
  // now only unique ones
  nodup[0][0] = edges[0][0];
  nodup[0][1] = edges[0][1];
  uc = 1;
  for(ii = 1; ii < rowCount; ii++) {
    if(isnew(edges[ii], nodup, uc)) {
      nodup[uc][0] = edges[ii][0];
      nodup[uc][1] = edges[ii][1];
      uc++;
    }
  }
  printf("\nfound %d unique entries; they are:\n", uc);
  for(ii = 0; ii < uc; ii++) {
    printf("%d %d\n", nodup[ii][0], nodup[ii][1]);
  }
}
```

Output (using the same file I used before):

```
all elements read in: 
2 3
3 4
4 5
3 4
4 3
1 2
2 3

found 5 unique entries; they are:
2 3
3 4
4 5
4 3
1 2
```

Comment: I want to write a C code that does that! I mean while reading the edges I want them to save them and check every edge if it already exists ... if it exists I do not take it into consideration any more! Thank you for your cooperation!

Comment: @user2700834 I have updated my answer with some sample C code.